# Type redefinition of identical definition

Tags: c++, c, typedef, redefinition

If I wanted to use a type, let's say `ulong` (part of POSIX), but did not know whether it was defined already, is it *guaranteed* that redefinition with the same definition is benign? This works in GCC, but I am unsure if it is defined in the C Standard.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // POSIX

/* 'ulong' already defined as 'unsigned long' */

typedef unsigned long ulong; // (Benign?) redefinition

int main(void) {
    ulong n = 5;

    printf("Result: %ld\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes, this is guaranteed by C11 and later, and C++98 and later.

### Long answer

For C, Section 6.7.3 of the C11 Standard states:

> - a `typedef`  name  may  be  redefined  to  denote  the  same  type  as  it  currently  does,provided that type is not a variably modified type;

This means that a type may be redefined so long as each definition is identical. Section 6.7.5 goes even further to state that only the first of these definitions (or the only definition) will be used by the compiler.

For C++, Section 7.1.3.3 of the C++98 Standard states:

> In a given scope<sup>1</sup>, a `typedef` specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.

This means that type redefinition is allowed in any non-class scope. Furthermore, in Section 7.1.3.6, it states:

> In a given scope, a `typedef` specifier shall not be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to a different type.

This means that redefinition is disallowed when the definition (*type*, in the documentation) is changed. As a result, the only time when we are unable to redefine a type is when subsequent definitions differ from the first, or--as Section 7.1.3.8 states--if the type name describes any of the following:

- an elaborated type specifier
- a class definition
- a constructor declaration, or
- a destructor declaration

**source:** [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/)

<sup>1</sup>In C++03 and later, scope must be non-class

Comment: @eerorika Good point. I will elaborate on my sources and add what the C++ standard states on the subject.

Comment: Note that this was added to ISO C in C11  , so may be rejected by older compilers (or newer compilers in old version compatibility mode)

Comment: @M.M Thank you  for the suggestion. I have added when each standard started specifying type redefinition.